# Advice moving from Eclipse to Xcode

Tags: eclipse, xcode

To Xcode xPerts:
I have been doing Java in Eclipse for about 9 years now and I have really gotten used to the power of the refactoring tools.  There are a few operations I do all the time.  I am looking for equivalents in Xcode since it has better support for objective-c than eclipse.  (I'm not at my Mac as I write this.  So some of this is from memory.  I am still very new to Xcode.)

## 1 "rename".

It seems that the Xcode equivalent for variables is "edit all in scope".  Does this work for files/classes/methods too?

## 2 "extract local variable"

select an expression it creates a local var initialized to that expression.  It even creates a usable name for the variable.

## 3 "extract method"

select some code and it will create a method with that code and appropriate parameters/return value.

## 4 "inline" (variable or method)

opposite of extract, inlines all or just the selected occurrence of the selected var or method.

## 5 "find next"

occurrence of selected text. In eclipse I can select some text and hit ctrl-k to go to the next occurrence of that in the file.  likewise shift-ctrl-k finds backwards.  IIRC the Xcode "find next" ignores the selection and only uses what is in the find box.

## 6 "change method signature"

This would be very useful with ocjective-c's named parameter messaging syntax.  This is great for adding parameters to a method.

## 7 "pull-up/push-down"

for moving methods up or down the class hierarchy.

## 8 "move"

for moving elements around to other classes etc.

Those are the ones that I use all of the time.  I have estimated that these tools cut my coding time in half.  Are any of these supported in Xcode?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: This is a great question and I look forward to refactoring enhancements of xcode

Answer (score 1):

You can read the Xcode user documentation on [Refactoring](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/RefactorWorkflow/RefactorWorkflow.html) on any machine.  It will answer most of these questions.

Answer (score 0):

For #1, if you right click a symbol name, you should have the `Refactor` menu option that permits you to rename the ivar, property, type name (including file names), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, right-click on a symbol then select Refactor.

There doesn't appear to be a "change method signature". I've used that feature for years in other IDEs. I guess the only thing to do in xcode is change the signature and hope that you get a compile error for everything that needs changing...not a great refactoring tool.

Xcode look slick in many ways, but there are some annoying omissions (anyone want to view the content of collections in the debugger?)